# The hierarchy of Liapounov conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

The general setup is an array $(X_{nj} : n \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \leq j \leq k_n)$ of random variables (where of course each $k_n$ is an integer of value at least $1$).

Write $S_{n} := \sum_{j=1}^{k_n} X_{nj}$ for the row sums.

We assume some independence and normalizations:

1. The random variables in each row are independent.
2. All the random variables have finite second moment.
3. $\mathbb{E}(X_{nj})=0 $ for all $n,j$.
4. $\mathrm{var}(S_n) = 1$ for all $n$.

In this context, say the array has the property $L(\delta)$ (for $\delta>0$) if

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{k_n} \mathbb{E} |X_{nj}|^{2+\delta} \longrightarrow 0 \quad \textrm{as} \quad n \rightarrow \infty. $$

The exercise I am stuck with asks me to show that: for $\delta < \delta'$, $L(\delta) \implies L(\delta')$.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication should be reversed because it is not even sure that $X_{n,j}$ has moments of order $2+\delta'$.

An idea could be the following: fix a positive $\varepsilon$, write 
$$ \tag{*}\mathbb E \left[|X_{n,j}|^{2+\delta}\right] \leqslant 
\varepsilon^\delta \mathbb E \left[|X_{n,j}|^{2
}\right]+\mathbb E \left[ \left(\frac{|X_{n,j}|}{\varepsilon}\right)^{2+\delta}\mathbf 1\{|X_{n,j}|\gt\varepsilon\}\right].$$
Then notice that 
$$\mathbb E \left[ \left(\frac{|X_{n,j}|}{\varepsilon}\right)^{2+\delta}\mathbf 1\{|X_{n,j}|\gt\varepsilon\}\right] \leqslant 
\mathbb E \left[ \left(\frac{|X_{n,j}|}{\varepsilon}\right)^{2+\delta'}\mathbf 1\{|X_{n,j}|\gt\varepsilon\}\right],$$
plug this into $(*)$, sum and take the $\limsup_{n\to \infty}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Davide. It is worth noting that to deal with the first term in $(*)$ hypothesis (4) is essential (then the sum over $j$ of the first term in $(*)$ becomes $\epsilon^{\delta}$) After the $\limsup$ in $n$ is taken, a further limit in $\epsilon$ is also then necessary. Also (for the sake of anyone using the same book from which this exercise comes who may stumble across this question)  I will add that the incorrect implication is as it appears in Chung's book 'A Course in Probability Theory' (the mistake is not corrected by the third edition!).